# How to change only the color of box-shadow with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some JS code to make the `box-shadow` of buttons a darker version of the buttons background color, where the user can dynamically change the button background colors.

My code works but I also need the `box-shadow` values to change on hover and my code is changing the whole property instead of just the color of the shadow.

```
$("input[type=submit]").each(function() {
    //get button color
    var btnclr = $(this).css("background-color");
    //make darker
    $(this).css({
        "box-shadow": "0 -3px 7px " + LightenDarkenColor(rgb2hex(btnclr), -80) + " inset"
    });
});
```

```css
input[type=submit] {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #555753;
    background-color: cor11;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 7px #888a85 inset;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #888a85 inset;
    text-shadow: 0 0;
}
```

I know I can make the hover animation in JS but the CSS is lighter and I would prefer not having to redo it in JS.

How about maybe turning the box shadow property into a string and only changing the color part of it?

Comment: first of all your background color code not right. Also you want to change your box shadow on hover but you didn't change your color on hover you use same color how it will work?

Comment: that's just it, i don't want to change the color on hover, just the shadow position. compare "box-shadow: 0 -3px 7px #888a85 inset" to "box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #888a85 inset"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will changes over all the css from input[type=submit] to input[type=submit]:hover, Instead use all the needed css again with the hover.

```
input[type=submit] {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #555753;
    background-color: cor11;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 -3px 7px #888a85 inset;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #555753;
    background-color: cor11;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #888a85 inset;
    text-shadow: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: my problem is the JS changing "box-shadow: 0 -3px 7px" to "box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px". see the button's background is a variable which the JS darkens so the box-shadow always looks good.